# Multithreading for similarity test in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, similarity

Hello I've been working on a huge csv file which needs similarity tests done. There is 1.16million rows and to test similarity between each rows it takes approximately 7 hours. I want to use multiple threads to reduce the time it takes to do so. My function which does the similarity test is:

```
def similarity():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        for j in range(i+1, 1000):
            longestSentence = 0
            commonWords = 0
            row1 = dff['Product'].iloc[i]
            row2 = dff['Product'].iloc[j]
            wordsRow1 = row1.split()
            wordsRow2 = row2.split()
            # iki tumcedede esit olan sozcukler
            common = list(set(wordsRow1).intersection(wordsRow2))
            if len(wordsRow1) > len(wordsRow2):
                longestSentence = len(wordsRow1)
                commonWords = calculate(common, wordsRow1)
            else:
                longestSentence = len(wordsRow2)
                commonWords = calculate(common, wordsRow2)
            print(i, j, (commonWords / longestSentence) * 100)


def calculate(common, longestRow):#esit sozcuklerin bulunmasi
    sum = 0
    for word in common:
        sum += longestRow.count(word)
    return sum
```

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor to do multithreading and the code to do so is:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(similarity()):
        print(result)
```

But even if I set max_workers to incredible amounts the code runs the same. How can I make it so the code runs faster? Is there any other way?

I tried to do it with threading library but it doesn't work because it just starts the threads to do the same job over and over again. So if I do 10 threads it just starts the function 10 times to do the same thing. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How many bytes is the file? **Why** do you have to use threads and not processes? Is it actually a csv file with commas separated fields? Can you operate on the file itself rather than using Pandas? How much freedom do you have? Can you run through the file and make 1 thousand smaller files?

Comment: It is for a project and it is cited in the project file that I have to use threads. It is a csv file separated by commas and have columns and rows(hence the dff['Product']). I can operate on file itself but I think it will be harder since pandas give me freedom of selecting which column or row I want work on. Other than these things I don't have any limitation.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for executor.map? Its arguments are a function object and an iterable. You are calling the function in your .map call.

Comment: Yes but I don't have anything to iterate over and it is a function that I got from the internet and now that I studied it a little bit it doesn't work like I want it to so I may remove it and go for another option for threading my calculations.

Comment: In your example you have hard coded the `'Product'` column, it doesn't look like that is *variable*.

Comment: How many bytes is the file?  Nominally how big is `dff['Product'].iloc[i]`?

Comment: Currently the file I am working on is 146.14mega-bytes.

Comment: You’ve mentioned a couple of times that the project requires you to use threads, and people have suggested processes instead. What would happen if you didn’t use threads… is this for a class, would you lose credit? I’m asking because it seems clear to me that threads are not the way to go, yet you have some constraint that requires them.

Comment: @ZachYoung yes it is for a project which I am working on during my internship. I asked a couple of times if I can use multiprocessing but their answer was no and that I need to remove GIL or just rewrite the project on C# or Java.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPoolExecutor will not actually help a lot because ThreadPool is more for IO tasks. Let's say you would do 500 API calls this would work but since you are doing heavy CPU tasks it does not work. You should use ProcessPoolExecutor but also point attention that making  max_workers numbers greater than the number of your cores will not do anything as well.
Also, your syntax is incorrect because you are running the same function inside your pool.
But I think you need to change your algorithm to make this work properly. There is definitely something wrong with your time compexity.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
 
values = [3,4,5,6]
def cube(x):
    print(f'Cube of {x}:{x*x*x}')
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result =[]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exe:
        exe.submit(cube,2)
         
        # Maps the method 'cube' with a iterable
        result = exe.map(cube,values)
     
    for r in result:
      print(r)
```

Comment: So there is no way that I can make my function use multithreading?

Comment: There is but it requires way more than you did and for your purpose, you need a process pool, not a thread. But I would suggest you to read about time complexity.
In your case doing 2 for loops is too much. You need to think of another way to make it faster.

Comment: This is for a project and project require me to use multithreading. That's why I've been trying to make it work but even making the similarity test work took too long(I am new to python). What your saying is I need to change the function which does the similarity test to be I/O bound and then I can use threads to make my work faster?

Comment: You are almost definitely doing something wrong if this takes 7 hours

Comment: It is 1.16million rows and every row is comparing itself with every other row so I think it is normal that it takes nearly 7 hours I didn't test it but based on calculations it took a thousand row to be tested in 25secs so a million rows it would take 25000secs which is nearly 7 hours.

Comment: @BerkSunduri That's 1.3+ *trillion* comparisons and CPU-bound.  Threading won't help since CPython has the global interpreter lock(GIL) and serializes all Python code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you very much for your comment. I arrived at the same conclusion and decided to not use threading.